# Print django filter context to template

Tags: python, django

I have a django view as follows

```
    tabledata = Entity.objects.filter(id=2)
context = {
        'table_data': tabledata,
    }
    return render(request, 'viewer.htm', context)
```

I tried printing the values in viewer.htm like so

```
{{table_data}}
```

This gives the output

```
 <QuerySet [<Entity: Entity object (6)>]>
```

I also tried printing the values using

```
{{table_data.A}}
```

which is one of the fields. This simply gives a blank output.

1.How do I print the values?

2.If the **filter** returns multiple rows, how do I print them individually in the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through your data:
For example:

```
<ul>
    {% for entitiy in table_data %}
      <li>{{ entity.A }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to retrieve the value of the first instance only. Something like {{table_data[0].A}}

Comment: Yes there is: It's called first :-) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#first

Answer (score 2):

in your template

```
{% for x in tabledata %}
    {{x.A}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to retrieve the value of the first instance only. Something like {{table_data[0].A}}

Comment: then you don't need the for-loop. Type `{{table_data[0].A}}` you will be able to get A field of the first instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that the query set returns a list of objects instead of a single object. Therefore you would need a for loop

```
{% for data in table_data %}
{{data.A}}
{%endfor%}
```